# Testing Actions on French Google Home device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I'm playing around with api.ai to add some possibilities to google assistant and the google home.

I've created a new project in "Action on google" with some very very simple interactions defined in a new agent in api.ai ( only one intent and a few possible responses)

following those steps: https://developers.google.com/actions/get-started/create-project-agent

I now try to test it on my device. I've first tested it in the simulator following those steps:
https://developers.google.com/actions/get-started/preview-the-app

So I can test it in the simulator by saying "talk to my test app". Unfortunatly I don't kow what to say to my home device to trigger the testing. (Note that my device in setup in FRENCH so it is maybe a language issue)

I've read that :

> all you need to do is log into the device using the same account that you used to authorize your action for testing in the simulator. Once you authorize your action for previewing, it will automatically be available on the Google Home device assigned to that same account. Note that you need to be authorized in the API.AI account under the same Google account in order for this to work!

I use only one google account, the same on home device, api.ai and google actions. This account is the owner of the new project when I check its permissions. So this should be fine.

Any idea would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (Oct. 6th 2017), you will be able to [set French as a language](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/agents)  for your API.ai bot and test it on a device or in the web simulator.

Make sure that you have also [configured the related Actions on Google app](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/publishing#provide_app_information_for_languages_and_locales) in English AND French (and eventually for the locales -- french (Europe) and french (Canada)). You must have one configuration per language/locale in your bot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info,  note that I had to update my draft in API.AI > integration > google assistant > update draft  AND in "actions on google" > overview > test draft.  to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while the Google Assistant has launched in French, Actions on Google hasn't yet. Until it does, there is no French support for testing actions except through the simulator (where you'll be testing in a different language).

Comment: Any ETA to give us?

Comment: I don't work for Google, and they typically do not announce things in advance. At the Google Developer Days Europe event held in early September they announced that French support would be "soon".

Comment: Thx for sharing